# How can I cut off circular dependency in api gateway and lambda in SAM template?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, sam

I have two lambda functions and one api gateway in SAM template. My template looks like,

```
Resources:
  TempApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: TempAuthorizer
        Authorizer:
          TempAuthorizer:
          FunctionPayloadType: REQUEST
          FunctionArn: !GetAtt TempAuthorizerFunction.Arn # This refers to Auth Function
          AuthorizerPayloadFormatVersion: "2.0"
          Identity:
            Headers:
              - Authorization
  TempAuthorizerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "TempAuth"
      Environment:
        Variables:
          API_RESOURCE_ARN: !Sub "arn::aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS:AccountId}:${TempApi}/*/POST/workwork/{eventName}" # This refers to api gateway
  LastFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "LastFunction"
```

```
# In my authorizer app.py I need to use API_RESOURCE_ARN
# authorizer/app.py
def temp_authorizer(event, context, logger, session):
    response = {
        "policyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [{
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": ... # It will be passed by lambda function API_RESOURCE_ARN
                "Effect": "Deny"
            }]
         },
         "context": {}
     }
```

How can I cut circular dependencies that I can use Api GateWay's Arn in TempAuthorizerFunction

Comment: Why do you need to pass API_RESOURCE_ARN into function? In event object there will be property `methodArn` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-input.html